# Not because the Radio Button sets the text?

Tags: android, radio-group

I created two functions a setText and other SetText 2, when rotating the screen I call setText or setText2 and the radio button does not change the text, but when you click the button it changes setText. It would be a component of the bug?

Github from project : https://github.com/guilhermehrcosta/Radio-Group-Bug

Comment: Try to call the setText on the UI thread

Comment: But when the instance is null save it changes.